# Not able to deploy war in Jboss EAP 6.4.0 through CLI

Tags: java, jboss, war, web.xml

While trying to deploy one war(cshw.war) file in Jboss EAP 6.4.0 I'm getting below error:

[standalone@localhost:9999 /] deploy /opt/csa/dat/**cshw.war**

{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.cshw.cshw.env.jdbc.CRLDS is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.CRLDS]"],"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {"Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".START","jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".START","jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".START","jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".START","jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".component.\"org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet\".START","jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".component.\"org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet\".START","jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".component.\"se.ericsson.security.cshw.CshwServlet\".START","jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".deploymentCompleteService","jboss.deployment.unit.\"cshw.war\".jndiDependencyService","jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cshw"],"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ejbca.ear\".\"ejbca-ws-ejb.jar\".deploymentCompleteService","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.ejbca.ejbca-ws-ejb.EjbcaWS","jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.CRLDS"]}}}}

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing some dependencies. If your project is a Maven project try adding the Maven Dependencies entry in your Deployment Assembly. If is not, ensure you added all the jars in both the Build Path and the Deployment Assembly.

Comment: I am not using Maven in this case, I have cross verified in web.xml file, it is mentioned and at the same time I have mentioned in standalone.xml file. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I just fixed the problem. I have created one more .xml file, named jboss-web.xml file and configured the JNDI and datasource there now I am able to deploy the application properly.